# How to handle user permissions in front-end with OAuth 2 in RestFul applications?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

Imagine we have an application that is implemented based-on restFul and OAuth2, and also of course we've stored the user's roles and permissions in the back-end which is implemented by Java and spring boot. So I want to know how can we handle the permissions of users in the front-end. Indeed, there are some fields or columns that should be shown to the user who has specific permission or role but other users can see limited fields or columns.

What is the most efficient and sensible solution to this situation?

- Should the front-end fetch available field or columns from the back-end?
- Should the front-end has all of the information about user credentials to decide?
- or is there any solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the most common solution, where all security is enforced by the API:

- API responses omit fields / columns that the user is not authorized to access
- UI can ask the API which fields / columns the user is authorized to access
- UI hides elements based on this API metadata

It is common to have an endpoint such as this, which the UI can send an access token to in order to get the above metadata:

- GET /api/userclaims/current